# xbox open source project

Tags: xbox360, open-source, xbox

im looking for some open source xbox project, I just wanna join it and try myself as game programmer, does anybody know such project?

Comment: What do you mean xbox project?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First off, this is a question and answer site, rather than a project finding site.

Secondly, you can only get an SDK for the Xbox if you are a licensed developer and pay a lot. So I doubt you'll find an open source one.

However, you can create Xbox Live Community Arcade (?) games with XNA and C#, for $99 a year for a license. They won't be open source, but you can join them. [Gamedev's help wanted forum](http://www.gamedev.net/forum/8-help-wanted/) is good.